# $O_p$ and $o_p$ notations in asymptotic normality proof

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, statistical-inference

I'm reading the proof of Theorem 5.21 (asymptotic normality of M-estimators) in van den Vaarts book "Asymptotic Statistics" (see the attached picture).

(The theorem assumes that $\hat{\theta}_n \to \theta_0$ in probability as $n\to \infty$; i.e., the estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ is asymptotically consistent.)

I do not understand the last paragraph of the proof. How did he go from the $\sqrt{n}$-consistency to the last conclusion? In particular,

- I do not see where the inequality in page 53 coming from?
- how the $o_p$ term of the last equation in page 52 vanished (I guess
  it      is represented now with the $o_p$ on the right hand side of
  that       equation).

It seems to me that the presentation (somehow) implies that
$$
O_p(1) + o_p(\sqrt{n} \|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0  \|) = O_p(1)\quad ?
$$
Does this hold? My understanding is that this should instead be $O_p(\max(1,\sqrt{n} \|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0  \| ))$.

However, if it does hold, then it will follow that
 $$\sqrt{n} \|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0  \| = O_p(1)$$ 
(we know that this is true if the LHS converges in distribution; however, this is something that we are trying to prove!) and therefore, 
 $$ o_p(\sqrt{n} \|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0  \| ) = o_p(O_p(1)) = o_p(1).$$

---

[image]

Comment: Well, they do assert that the left hand side is bounded in probability, so yes it would follow that the $O_P(1) + o_P(LHS)=O_P(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that if $(1 + o_p(1))X_n = O_p (1)$ then $X_n =(1 + o_p(1))^{-1} O_P(1) = O_p(1) O_p(1) = O_p(1)$ then second equality comes from the section of van der Vaart book on the $O_p$ notation.

Does it make sense?